# System.DirectoryServices being imported (VB.NET) and referenced (web.config) but build error given

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, directoryservices, visual-web-developer

I have a .net v4 web application built in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express which functions as I expect and currently uses a logon screen. I wanted to add in the System.DirectoryServices namespace, so to my web.config I added:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

and to my Default.aspx.vb I added :

Imports System.DirectoryServices

I checked that the System.DirectoryServices is referenced in the "Website"->"Add Reference"->".NET" menu option. I clicked on the System.DirectoryServices option in that dialogue box but nothing appears to happen at that point.

However if I look at "Website"->"Start Options"->"References" I see:
System.DirectoryServices GAC 4.0.0.0

However when I come to build my application, I get the error:

warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.DirectoryServices' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Any ideas?
Thanks